# Can we get Grand total for a column in Excel pivot which is not a measure

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I was wondering can we get grand total of a column field in Excel pivot which is not a measure.
I have one pivot in which I am pulling revenue($) as row field and not as a value field due to some limitations. Is it possible to have total for that.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lol0i.png)

Comment: `not a measure`??  Do you mean not a **value**?  It would make more sense if you post images of what you have, what you tried, what the problem is, and what you need.  If you have a number stored as text, you should convert it to a number before using it in your pivot table, perhaps with the `VALUE` function

Comment: Yes. Not a value. but as a row I have added that column(it is revenue in $). I tried playing with field settings and pivot table options but that didn't work. I have added a sample image in question.
I want total  for first column. Is it possible?